# Field is not writable for opportunity team member Name

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, opportunity-teams

Getting an error like **An Apex error occurred: System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: OpportunityTeamMember.UserId**

```
public class BD_UPDATEOppTeam {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void OppTeamDelete(List<Id> OpportunityIds)
    {
        List<OpportunityTeamMember> mem = [select id,UserId from OpportunityTeamMember
                                          where Opportunity.id in :OpportunityIds
                                          and TeamMemberRole =: 'Opportunity Owner'];

        for(Opportunity oppt :[select id,ownerId from Opportunity where Opportunity.id in :OpportunityIds]){

            for(OpportunityTeamMember team :mem){
                 team.UserId= oppt.ownerId;
            }
        }


        update mem;
   }


}
```

How to resolve this issues?
Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

The field cannot be written to, because [it is listed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityteammember.htm) as "creatable" only. You must *delete* the old record and *create* a new record.

Comment: Hi, but when I tried to delete it cause the this error  : FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00qK0000003mcOUIAY; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Can't remove a team member assigned to a split from an opportunity.: []

Comment: @Jury then, you'd have to delete the split first. You need to follow the errors' directions.

Comment: Yes, But we cant write any apex code delete split assigned to opportunity know?